# javascript - replace() delete all the repeat letter in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to delete all the repeat letter in a string with javascript.

```js
mot = "message in a bottle";
mot = mot.replace(/[\w]{2,}/i, '');

console.log(mot)
// result wish : "mesage in a botle"`
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The text doesn't fit to the goal, perhaps you could elaborate the question ..?

Answer (score 2):

You can group the word characters and then use a backreference to check if the same character follows that grouped character (with `\1`). You can replace all found occurrences with the group using `$1`. Ensure that you use the global flag (`/g`) to match all occurrences:

```js
const mot = "message in a bottle";
const res = mot.replace(/(\w)\1/ig, '$1');
console.log(res);
```